# How to create two BulkSendApplications?

Tags: networking, tcp, ns-3

I want to use two BulkSendApplications to send from node_0 to node_1 and from node_2 to node_3.
My code for creating the applications looks the following:

```
  // node_0 to node_1

  uint16_t rcv_port = 50000;
  PacketSinkHelper sink1 ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory",
                         Address (InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), rcv_port)));
  ApplicationContainer sinkApps1 = sink1.Install (node_1);
  sinkApps1.Start (MilliSeconds (0));
  sinkApps1.Stop (MilliSeconds (start_sending_traffic + traffic_duration));

  BulkSendHelper source1 (
      "ns3::TcpSocketFactory",
      Address (InetSocketAddress (node_1, rcv_port)));
  ApplicationContainer sourceApps1 = source1.Install (node_0);
  source.SetAttribute ("MaxBytes", UintegerValue (0));
  sourceApps1.Start (MilliSeconds (start_sending_traffic));
  sourceApps1.Stop (MilliSeconds (start_sending_traffic + traffic_duration));

  // node_2 to node_3

  uint16_t rcv_port2 = 50001;
  PacketSinkHelper sink2 ("ns3::TcpSocketFactory",
                          Address (InetSocketAddress (Ipv4Address::GetAny (), rcv_port2)));
  ApplicationContainer sinkApps2 = sink2.Install (node_3);
  sinkApps2.Start (MilliSeconds (0));
  sinkApps2.Stop (MilliSeconds (start_sending_traffic + traffic_duration));

  BulkSendHelper source2 (
      "ns3::TcpSocketFactory",
      Address (InetSocketAddress (node_3, rcv_port2)));
  ApplicationContainer sourceApps2 = source2.Install (node_2);
  source2.SetAttribute ("MaxBytes", UintegerValue (0));
  sourceApps2.Start (MilliSeconds (start_sending_traffic));
  sourceApps2.Stop (MilliSeconds (start_sending_traffic + traffic_duration));
```

The code is the same for both, just with the correct nodes. If I run this code, node_0->node_1 is transmitting the correct amount of traffic while node_2->node_3 is not transmitting anything.
I am checking the amount of bits received with the following code snippet:

```
  Ptr<PacketSink> s1 = DynamicCast<PacketSink> (sinkApps1.Get (0));
  std::cout << "Total Bits Received: " << s1->GetTotalRx () * 8 << std::endl;
  Ptr<PacketSink> s2 = DynamicCast<PacketSink> (sinkApps2.Get (0));
  std::cout << "Total Bits Received: " << s2->GetTotalRx () * 8 << std::endl;
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here? Am I using the constructors the wrong way?

Comment: Apart from other mistakes in your code, I think you should change 0 to your desired sink in sinkApps2.Get (0)); If it doesn't work, I can't see any possible solution.

Comment: I will try that out right away. Care to tell me what other mistakes you found?

Comment: source.SetAttribute should be source1.SetAttribute.

Comment: I looked into the examples/tcp/tcp-bulk-send.cc. But it is designed for 2 nodes. So, I couldn't replicate your example code.

Comment: Oh yes. But that was only a minor error in copying the code in a "readable" format to stackoverflow. Also I looked at the "sinkApps2.Get (0));": As there is only one sink in sinkApps1 and one in sinkApps2, I think it makes sense to access the first element (index 0).

Comment: @a4arshad the examples from tcp-bulk-send.cc are indeed only for 2 nodes. I just took that and basically added the code above. In other words just duplicated the creation of the sink and source. Any thoughts why this is not working?

Comment: From your question, what I understood is; you're trying to compute the received data over sink. In this example, you have two sinks. So, both cannot be 0. What do you think?

Comment: But I do sinkApps1.Get (0) the first time and sinkApps2.Get (0) the second. So they are two different ApplicationContainers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211282/discussion-between-erebosm-and-a4arshad).